# Difference between using Windows Backup and copying each file separately

Tags: hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, windows-backup

I have an external hard drive, and I want to back up my computer to this drive. As I'm doing it for the first time, the following questions have cropped up in my mind:

What is the difference between using Windows Backup and copying files? If I copy each and every file rather than back up, how will it differ? Which is more preferable and why?

My computer is running on Windows 7 Professional 32-bit, 4GB of RAM.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Ramhound this amount of information is making the question unclear? What are you specifically finding unclear?

Comment: I can clearly see four different questions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Ramhound very well, I've reduced to one question.

Comment: Copying files to a second volume is backing those files up.  There isn't any difference unless your using software to do it, and that software, uses a [proprietary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_format) and created an backup archive (.tib,ect).

Comment: @Ramhound so, I can use any option?

Comment: Copying files may be a form of backup. What do you mean exactly? You may be confused by the process known as [*imaging*](https://superuser.com/a/1223774/194694), which is also a form of backup.

Comment: @gronostaj I don't know what's imaging. I wanted to use Windows Backup, and thus wanted to know the difference between backup and copy.

Comment: @WrichikBasu - You can use any backup method you want that meets your backup requirements.  Data retention is a huge field.  Windows Backup is a very basic solution to backup your user profile.  If you need anything more then to backup the files within your user's profile directory you should be using something other than Windows Backup (even if that was your only requirement I wouldn't use it).

Comment: That explains why you are confused. I've edited the question for you, I believe it's clearer now. I can't write a comprehensive answer right now, but you can google for "incremental backup" to learn why it's cool.

Comment: @gronostaj actually, I don't need to create a system image as stated in the link. A simple copy of files would be enough. Bootloader copy is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you use some backup product to back up your data (for example, a folder), the archive attribute will be cleared (meaning that this file has been backed up). If you make some changes to the data after you back up this data, the archive attribute will be selected automatically to indicate that the data has been changed since the last save. So, next time the backup utility runs, it will check all the files archive attributes to see which data has been changed since the last backup.

You can see this attribute by clicking **Advanced** button on the General tab of the folder's property. It is the "Folder is ready for archiving".

So, if you have more than one backup product to regularly backup your files and after the initial backup some files have been changed. These changed file's archive attribute will be selected. One backup utility runs and finds that the files have been changed, it will back up these files and then clears the archive attribute. After that, another backup utility runs, however, it will find that the archive attribute is not selected, so it will see this file as unchanged since the last backup. Conclusively, after a long time, you will find the backup files are not the same within the different backup products.

The total difference between these two options is, copy backup copies all the files that you select, but does not mark each file as having been backed up (in other words, the archive attribute is not cleared).

So since you're having an external hard drive, and want to back up my computer to the drive, I would recommend your run a Windows Backup so that all your files are backed up and you will preserve all the applications files including log files on the computer, rather than copying selected files.

**Resource**: [Backup](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/97aac730-ed3b-44bf-b145-42d14868dbd9/vss-full-backup-vs-vss-copy-backup)